# Eclipse compiling .jar file with Source code, and no .class files

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, intellij-idea

I apologize if this is an absolutely dunce question. I typically use Intellij Idea, and I'm not quite so familiar with Eclipse, so maybe this is part of my problem. I'm trying to compile a jar, I've done the export, as jar file, and checked "create .class files" in the output options, I click finish, and it "compiles" the jar file for me in the output.

I go to check the .jar file (open in Winrar) and the .jar file contains a folder named src, with all the .java source code, and there are no .class files in the .jar file. I figured maybe I could just change the file extension, because I thought maybe it just didn't change the extension, but when I got to view the file, it is clear that it hasn't even been parsed, as it is still in source format.

I receive no compile errors when I try to export it in Eclipse. I do have build errors for the entire project, but I'm not so worried about the entire project, I just wanted to compile one .jar file. And the build errors are not relating to the .jar file I'm trying to build, they are related to other files. Is it necessary to fix every build error to compile one .jar file? I'm just not quite sure why it would "compile" with no build errors, and then not actually compile.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: not an answer but try NetBeans, it creates a jar automatically for every build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your project > select Export... > select if your project is runnable or only JAR > check the option "Export Java source files and resources" > Finish